# Is there a fix for the NoClassDefFoundError for GarbageCollectorExtImpl?

Tags: java-9

I ran into a Java 9b78 problem. It would be expected that an error like this would come up, but this was also a problem in b68 as well.

I thought I would use Java 9 and attempt to play minecraft on it for java's performance improvements. I got the following stack trace message:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sun/management/internal/GarbageCollectorExtImpl
    at sun.management.MemoryImpl.getMemoryManagers0(Native Method)
    at sun.management.MemoryImpl.getMemoryManagers(MemoryImpl.java:98)
    at sun.management.ManagementFactoryHelper.getGarbageCollectorMXBeans(ManagementFactoryHelper.java:130)
    at java.lang.management.DefaultPlatformMBeanProvider$4.nameToMBeanMap(DefaultPlatformMBeanProvider.java:185)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.lambda$getPlatformMBeanServer$0(ManagementFactory.java:478)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$7$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:269)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline$2$1.accept(ReferencePipeline.java:177)
    at java.util.HashMap$ValueSpliterator.forEachRemaining(HashMap.java:1664)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.copyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:482)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.wrapAndCopyInto(AbstractPipeline.java:472)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:151)
    at java.util.stream.ForEachOps$ForEachOp$OfRef.evaluateSequential(ForEachOps.java:174)
    at java.util.stream.AbstractPipeline.evaluate(AbstractPipeline.java:234)
    at java.util.stream.ReferencePipeline.forEach(ReferencePipeline.java:430)
    at java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:479)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.jmx.Server.registerMBeans(Server.java:107)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.core.impl.Log4jContextFactory.<init>(Log4jContextFactory.java:59)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:425)
    at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:465)
    at org.apache.logging.log4j.LogManager.<clinit>(LogManager.java:85)
    at azo.<clinit>(SourceFile:200)
    at net.minecraft.client.main.Main.main(SourceFile:42)
```

Minecraft isn't the only program experiencing this error apparently: https://josm.openstreetmap.de/ticket/11577

Comment: Could be that Minecraft uses proprietary api, or that Java 9 is just not ready for it's big debut.

Comment: Obviously the problem is java.lang.management.ManagementFactory.getPlatformMBeanServer(ManagementFactory.java:479)

Comment: I should note this is the x64 version. It could be a Java SE server problem, whereas the client version might work just fine.